# Why my route is not working perfectly in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, facade

I am using Laravel 8 with `fortify` auth without Jetstream.

`web.php`

```php
Route::get('/facade_version', function () {
    dd('EXAMPLE');
})->name('postcard.facade');
```

> Above is my route

`index.blade.php`

```php
<a href="{{ route('postcard.facade') }}" type="a" class="btn btn-success">facade postcard</a>
```

### Output in Screen

> `Route [postcard.facade] not defined. (View: E:\github\LARAVEL\laravel8-fortify\resources\views\facade\index.blade.php)`

I tried with second way using `http://127.0.0.1:8000/facade_version` in url

### Output in Screen

`404 | Not Found`

Everything is ok But I could not figure it out whats the problem.

I have done this kind of route before with same way.

But this is not working

Look at the below route. it works perfectly.

```php
Route::get('/post-cards', function () {
    $postcardService = new PostcardSendingService('USA', 4, 6);
    $postcardService->hello('Hello from Coder Tape USA!!', 'imrul.cse273@gmail.com');
})->name('postcard.index');
```

- I just edit the link to `/post-cardsss` instead of `/post-cards`' then again the route is not found

### Note

Today I ran these commands in my projects

```php
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: Hello, is your file path to the blade view something like `/resources/views/postcard/facade.blade.php`? I'm assuming you are using the default Laravel view path configuration, and not using a route prefix inside a route group or something. The dot notation in route names indicates file paths. Please post a tree view of your `views` folder configuration, if you are able. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using this command

```php
php artisan route:clear
```

And run the project again

Answer (score 0):

I have tried those steps from laravel documentation and solved my issue

```
composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev
```

and then

```
php artisan config:cache
```

and again

```
php artisan route:cache
```

this was the most important may as we were missing route information

```
php artisan view:cache
```

Great laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/deployment) is here

Thank you.